# Cannot get account list: ERROR: Invalid JSON RPC response:

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, testrpc

I am new to solidity and smart contracts and I'm trying to deploy my contract from remix using a web3 environment. I have testrpc running in command prompt. When I try to deploy, I get the error mentioned in the title on remix and in my command prompt I get the error: "Error: Callback was already called.

```
at C:\Users\james\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:23011:36 "
```

In addition, under the environment section in Remix, it changes to say "Can't detect Network" instead of the "Web3 provider custom 1542..." it should say.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The `ethereumjs-testrpc` was deprecated several years ago. I'll suggest to use [ganache-cli](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli) instead.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! Really appreciate the help!